# CocoaPods Validating pod spec while pod trunk push

Tags: ios, iphone, png, cocoapods

I am trying to push a new `PodSpec` for my repository called `DKProgressHUD` using `pod trunk push command`. It tells, that my image is invalid. So, I have two questions. Does trunk already available for pushes. What is wrong with my image?

```
~/Documents/Github/DKProgressHUD: $ pod trunk push ./DKProgressHUD.podspec
Validating podspec
 -> DKProgressHUD (1.0.1)
    - WARN  | The screenshot https://github.com/wzbozon/DKProgressHUD/blob/master/Screenshot.png is not a valid image.

[!] The podspec does not validate.
```

This is image: 
[image]

Link to [GitHub/DKProgressHUD](https://github.com/wzbozon/DKProgressHUD).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is most likely that the link is not a link to the image itself, but to a Github page about the image.

Using the raw image should help: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wzbozon/DKProgressHUD/master/Screenshot.png

Here is an excerpt of the code that raises the error:

```
def validate_screenshots(spec)
  spec.screenshots.compact.each do |screenshot|
    request = validate_url(screenshot)
    if request && !(request.headers['content-type'] && request.headers['content-type'].first =~ /image\/.*/i)
      warning "The screenshot #{screenshot} is not a valid image."
    end
  end
end
```

I hope this helps. Cheers!